# Getting 404 error with Sails JS one way association

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I have 2 models. I would like to associate 2 models.

**Manufacturers.js**

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    manufacturer_name: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    manufacturer_logo_url: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    manufacturer_archived_status: {
      type: 'boolean'
    },
    manufacturer_tabs: {
      model: 'manufacturer_tabs'
    }
  }
};
```

**Manufacturer_tabs.js**

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    tab_name: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    manufacturer_fields: {
      model: 'manufacturer_fields'
    }
  }
};
```

After adding manufacturer when I try to create a tab within manufacturer, I'm getting 404 error.

```
POST http://localhost:1337/manufacturers/5acf62cf080d700c2209d40b/manufacturer_tabs
```

POST Body

```
{
    "tab_name": "tab1"
}
```

I'm using blueprint `POST /:model/:id/:association/`

Comment: Are you `POST /:model/:id/:association` is a blueprint route? I can't find reference to it in the docs (https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/blueprints/blueprint-routes). You may have to create the associated model, then use the add route after completion.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a `fk` id, in sails v1.0 the blueprint route is : `PUT /:model/:id/:association/:fk`

see [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/add-to), the `manufacturer_tabs` record has to be already in the database, that's why you have to provide his id : `fk`.